# Validate if hazelcast indexes are used

Tags: java, scala, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using Hz PredicateBuilder to query Hz maps with query on nested object's attribute. Have created an index on the nested field too in config file.

```
EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
Predicate idPredicate = e.get( "id" ).equal( id );
Predicate predicate = e.get( "rel.id" ).equal( rel.id).and(idPredicate);
return personMap.values( predicate );
```

Where rel is an object with id attribute and is an attribute of Person object.

```
 indexes = [
            {
              attribute = id
              isOrdered = false
            },
            {
              attribute = rel.id
              isOrdered = false
            }
          ]
```

Correct records are returning but want to make sure if this query is using the index. Is there a way to make sure this query is using the index? (Any informational message or something). Worked with DB2 before and debug level shows these messages. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Believe me with enough records In Memory if you are not using the index you will notice. Especially if you start more then one member , because of the remote traffic.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Thanks! Actually we were using predicates earlier and indexes were not used. So we are moving to PredicateBuilder since it is indexaware class so just want to make sure than purpose is met. Although  with these changes preformance is definitely better.

Comment: Have you read this ? Unfortunately It does not look like there is statistics MBean relevant to the Indexes but you can easily measure the times with the index enabled and then with the index disabled http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/management.html

Comment: Basically if the indexes are not hit it will start deserializing the objects and this will not go unnoticed. Especially when you include the remoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Hazelcast documentation - Management section. No  statistic object for Indexes is listed. The listed statistics MBeans are the different distributed objects.

At the same time if index is not hit this will result in sequential deserialization of the keys and potentially also values if we are queuing the values as well. With enough records in memory 100 000+ probably even less the performance difference will be more than noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question!

If you use exactly the same nested attribute path in the query as in the index definition than you can be 100% sure that the index will be used (if the predicate is IndexAware).

In order to test it empirically you can execute two queries on a big examplary data set (like 1M entries). Let one of them use the index and the other one some other nested attribute (with the same nesting level). You will see that the execution time differ **significantly**.